# PMSM Motor Permanent Magnet Flux Linkage

Tags: motor-controller, magnetic-flux, pmsm, vector-control

I want to know the Permanent Magnet Flux Linkage of my PMSM motor. I need that to implement a Speed control for my motor. Without this value I cannot do the necessary calculations to make the motor rotate. The motor I am using is a 400W PMSM motor. Rated Current and voltage is 2.6A and 108V respectively. Motor name is HG-KR43.

If there are any specific equations used, please tell me how to use them. Only the rated values are known in the motor datasheet. Rest I would like to know how to find

Comment: Have you read the data sheet for the motor and, if you have, maybe there are forums of other users you can ask. Have you done these things?

Comment: Yes the motor specifications does not contain the flux linkage value. What other forums do you suggest I should ask this in?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.